# Windows Vista freezes on Dell Latitude XT

Tags: windows-vista, freeze, dell-latitude

After 15 minutes of use Windows Vista simply freezes on me like in the good old times.

How to prevent it? Why no BSOD?

Recently Dell's WiFi driver has been updated.

Comment: After 3 freezes I've decided to do a system restore. Maybe the Dells wifi driver is faulty... will see

Comment: Get your hands on Process Explorer from Sysinternals. Monitor what causes the memory leak (because this is what's happening). If you can pin it down to the WiFi card (usually svchost), then you're in the land of "screwed". My eventual remedy was to find an older driver for my card.

Comment: Is computer hotter than usually? Is it hotter in bios?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that Windows is scanning regularly for Wireless networks, even if you're already connected.

You may disable this behavior using [WLAN Optimizer](http://www.martin-majowski.de/wlanoptimizer/) or [Vista Anti-Lag](http://www.codecase.de/software/downloads/file/18-val-v1-1-1-setup).